# Скрыть путь админ панели Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento

Добрый день, интересует способы смены пути к админ панели в Magento 1,9. К примеру 1 - через /app/etc/local.xml. Какие еще есть? Может php исходник админ панели подправить, что бы он откликался на другой путь, не как в local.xml. А то меня не устраивает смена путь через xml файл. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Да, попробуйте в

> system->configuration->advanced->admin->Admin Base URL menu
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]